# ¿Hay alguna forma de pasar el valor de una variable al value de un input mediante PHP?

Tags: php

Buenas, tal y como muestra la pregunta, quería saber si es posible solo con PHP ya que veo ejemplos pero lo hacen con JavaScript. Les agradecería su pudieran poner un ejemplo para tomarlo como referencia.

```
    <?PHP
        if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){
            $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
            $apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];
            $edad = $_POST['edad'];
            $provincia = $_POST['provincias'];
            $dni = $_POST['dni'];
            $sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
            $cp = 0;

            switch($provincia){
                case "Palencia":   $cp = 1010;
                      break;

                case "Valladolid": $cp = 1020;
                      break;

                case "Salamanca": $cp = 1030;
                      break;

                case "Burgos": $cp = 1040;
                      break;

                case "Avila": $cp = 1050;
                      break;

                case "Soria": $cp = 1060;
                      break;

                case "Segovia": $cp = 1070;
                      break;

                case "Zamora": $cp = 1080;
                      break;       
            }
       }
    ?>

  <form action="<?PHP echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
       <div>
            <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" name="nombre" size="15"><br/><br/>
            <label for="apellido">Apellidos</label>
            <input type="text" name="apellido" size="25"/><br/><br/>
            <label for="edad">Edad</label>
            <input type="text" name="edad" size="4"/><br/><br/>
            <label for="proincias">Pais</label>
            <select id="" name="provincias">
                <option value = "Palencia">Palencia</option>
                <option value = "Valladolid">Valladolid</option>
                <option value = "Salamanca">Salamanca</option>
                <option value = "Burgos">Burgos</option>
                <option value = "Avila">Avila</option>
                <option value = "Soria">Soria</option>
                <option value = "Segovia">Segovia</option>
                <option value = "Zamora">Zamora</option>
            </select><br/><br/>
            <label for="cp">CP</label>
            <input type="text" name="cp" value="<?PHP ?>" size="10" disabled /><br/><br/>
            <label for="dni">DNI</label>
            <input type="text" name="dni" size="10"/><br/><br/>
            <input type="radio"  id="" name="sexo" value="hombre" />Hombre
        <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="mujer" />Mujer<br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="enviar"/>
        </div>
    </form> 
</body>
```

Lo que intento es que según valla seleccionando cada provincia me muestre el codigo de provincia pero establecido en un input en la que le llamo CP (Código Postal). Ahí en el value lo estaba intentando pero lo deje a media XD

Comment: Puedes poner cómo lo estás intentando?

Comment: ¿Podrías explicarnos paso a paso qué quieres hacer? Primero muestras el input con un valor vacío y solicitas a un PHP su contenido o quieres generar directamente el campo del formulario con el dato relleno?

Comment: Claro ahora paso mi ejemplo

Comment: ¿Te sirvió alguna respuesta? Si es así recuerda votar aquellas que te ayudaron con un positivo y marcar la correcta. Gracias.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El código que necesitas es el siguiente:

```
<input type="text" name="cp"
  value="<?= isset($cp)?htmlspecialchars($cp):'' ?>"
  size="10" disabled />
<br/><br/>
```

Fíjate en el uso de [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) para que los caracteres especiales de HTML como las comillas (") se conviertan en entidades HTML como `&quote;` y así no te rompa la etiqueta HTML ni sufras [ataques XSS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Aunque el valor de `$cp` está acotado y lo tienes controlado, siempre es buena práctica usar dicha función para que en caso de que cambies el código o la forma en la que calculas el código postal no abras un agujero en la seguridad de tu página.

Además, he hecho uso de [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) para evitar un mensaje de advertencia diciendo que la variable no está definida cuando la página se carga antes de enviar el formulario y definirse el valor de ésta.

El [operador ternario `?:`](http://php.net/operators.comparison#language.operators.comparison.ternary) (`isset($cp)?htmlspecialchars($cp):''`) se usa para evitar un bloque `if` comprobando si existe `$cp` y si lo está muestra su contenido y en caso contrario mostrará una cadena vacía (o lo que tú quieras, simplemente debes cambiar el `''` por cualquier otra cosa como `'00000'`, por ejemplo).

Si no quieres que el usuario sepa qué valor tiene ese campo puedes ocultarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cp"
  value="<?= isset($cp)?htmlspecialchars($cp):'' ?>"
  size="10" disabled />
<br/><br/>
```

El código completo queda:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        $apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];
        $edad = $_POST['edad'];
        $provincia = $_POST['provincias'];
        $dni = $_POST['dni'];
        $sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
        $cp = 0;

        switch($provincia){
            case "Palencia":   $cp = 1010;
                  break;

            case "Valladolid": $cp = 1020;
                  break;

            case "Salamanca": $cp = 1030;
                  break;

            case "Burgos": $cp = 1040;
                  break;

            case "Avila": $cp = 1050;
                  break;

            case "Soria": $cp = 1060;
                  break;

            case "Segovia": $cp = 1070;
                  break;

            case "Zamora": $cp = 1080;
                  break;       
        }
   }
?>

<form action="<?PHP echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
   <div>
        <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" name="nombre" size="15"><br/><br/>
        <label for="apellido">Apellidos</label>
        <input type="text" name="apellido" size="25"/><br/><br/>
        <label for="edad">Edad</label>
        <input type="text" name="edad" size="4"/><br/><br/>
        <label for="proincias">Pais</label>
        <select id="" name="provincias">
            <option value="Palencia">Palencia</option>
            <option value="Valladolid">Valladolid</option>
            <option value="Salamanca">Salamanca</option>
            <option value="Burgos">Burgos</option>
            <option value="Avila">Avila</option>
            <option value="Soria">Soria</option>
            <option value="Segovia">Segovia</option>
            <option value="Zamora">Zamora</option>
        </select><br/><br/>
        <label for="cp">CP</label>
        <input type="text" name="cp"
          value="<?= isset($cp)?htmlspecialchars($cp):'' ?>"
          size="10" disabled />
        <br/><br/>
        <label for="dni">DNI</label>
        <input type="text" name="dni" size="10"/><br/><br/>
        <input type="radio"  id="" name="sexo" value="hombre" />Hombre
    <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="mujer" />Mujer<br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="enviar"/>
    </div>
</form> 
</body>
```

Comment: Muy completa la respuesta

Comment: Gracias por la explicación!

Comment: Un placer ser de ayuda :)

Answer (score 4):

Con [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.htmlspecialchars.php):

```
<input type="text" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($tuvariable);?>" />
```

Si utilizas una versión anterior a php 5.4

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($tuvariable); ?>" />
```

Adaptado a tu código

```
<input type="text" name="cp" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($cp); ?>" size="10" disabled />`
```

Comment: Como no se con que versión de php trabaja he preferido dejarlo con el `<?php echo`.

Comment: En PHP **SIEMPRE** está disponible `<?=`, sea la versión que sea y se configure como se configure PHP.

Comment: En la página oficial indican que versiones anteriores a `PHP 5.4.0` no funciona por defecto, hay que activar : `short_open_tag`. Fuente: http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

Comment: En versiones muy antiguas (PHP 5.3 y anteriores) `<?` estaba relacionada con `<?=`, a partir de 5.4 no. A partir de PHP 5.4 el funcionamiento de `<?=` es independiente del estado de `short_open_tag` y está **SIEMPRE** activa y se considera una etiqueta estándar como la `<?php`. Además, PHP 5.3 está obsoleto y fuera de ciclo de vida desde [el 14 de agosto de 2014](http://php.net/eol) (hace más de tres años), debería usarse como mínimo PHP 5.6.

Answer (score 3):

Simplemente debes imprimir la variable en el atributo `value` de tu `input`

```
<input type="text" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($varibable); ?>">
```

Y eso es todo

Comment: Ponerlo directamente es una mala práctica, c&p: ciertos caracteres tienen un significado especial en HTML y deben ser representados por entidades HTML si se desea preservar su significado. Tienes más información en: http://php.net/manual/es/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: @HamzaAkiour Oh no sabia eso, gracias !!

Comment: @OscarGarcia gracias por la aclaración !

Comment: @OscarGarcia gracias nuevamente por la alcaración, no me gusta mucho editar cuando me equivoco ya que es bueno que se vean los errores para que alguien aprenda y no los cometa, pero te hice caso y ya edité mi respuesta !

Answer (score 2):

Con PHP solo podrás aplicar el valor en el momento de crear el html statico en el servidor para ser enviado al browser del cliente. Si lo que pretendes es modificar un valor en base al comportamiento del usuario, etc.. Solo lo podrás hacer con Javascript ya que PHP corre únicamente del lado del servidor.

```
PHP - Sentencia echo
Ejem: <img src="<?php echo './miLogotipo.jpg' ?>">

Javascript - elemento.setAttribute('nombre del atributo', 'valor a poner')
Ejem: document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].setAttribute("src", "./miLogotipo.jpg")
```

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad @AlbertoLasa. Pásate por [cómo escribo una buena respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para aprender cómo redactar una respuesta con mayor calidad. Separa texto de código para que no se entremezclen.